# Flask app not returning JSON errors

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm creating a flask app and I'm using [this snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/83/) to always return JSON errors instead of HTTP.

I'm quite new to Flask but as I understand the snippet it should replace all errors with JSON, but it doesn't do that for me.

For example, if I visit an url not handled by Flask routes (`/users1` instead of `/users`), I get a JSON response back. But if I try to visit `/user/10` and user with id 10 doesn't exist, I get an error in this code:

```
@app.route('/users/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_user(id):
    user = queries.get_single_user(id)

    return jsonify(
        { 'data' : user.serialize() }
    )
```

Since user is `None` in this case, I get an exception, which is all good, but to the client an HTTP respons is sent, not a JSON.

Why is this and how do I only send JSON when there is an error? I know I can create my own errors and do try/catch, but that's not what I'm after.

My question is, how do I wrap all error responses and only send the JSON, never HTTP

Comment: what HTTP response your client got? is that something like `500`?

Comment: can you paste a sample of what `queries.get_single_user(id)` returns ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `user = ...` statement under `try/except` and always return `jsonify(dict)`, something like this:

```
@app.route('/users/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_user(id):
    try:
        user = queries.get_single_user(id)
        res = {'data': user.serialize()}
    except User.DoesNotExist: # or except the specific Error you get from above
        res = {'data': 'user not found'}

    return jsonify(res)
```

And you can also update the `res` response with whatever you've defined using the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `Flask jsonify` method like this :

```
@app.route('/users/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_user(id):
    user = queries.get_single_user(id)
    if user:
        return jsonify(data=user.serialize())

    return jsonify(data="No results found")
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP is asking why errors are sent as HTML instead of JSON.

Comment: Yes, like Erik says, this does not answer my question. I'm wondering why my responses aren't in the form of JSON instead of HTTP.

Comment: But, you syntax for jsonify is much better than mine, thanks!